# Custom API paths

Tags: 8

How can I add custom path to API requests?

Say `mysite.com/{api}/user/login.json`

Is there an option to do this?

Comment: Can you give us some more details. you can set endpoint in your services ui

Comment: You have to create a route(path) and a controller. See the *.routing.yml files for core modules to see how are they doing it and read about routing in D8 in here https://www.drupal.org/node/2116767

Comment: @IvanJaros Use answers for answering questions, not comments.

Comment: @Berdir a proper answer should contain explanation and possible examples. Hence I don't consider this a proper answer but rather a mere suggestion.

Comment: @IvanJaros yes thats an option can i extend these for built in `routes` too ?

Comment: Depends..if you want to append something to existing path, that would be a new paths so no issue there. If you would change the existing paths you can break your site if you don't know what you're doing. To alter existing routes define event subscriber service and use Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\EventSubscriberInterface or \Drupal\Core\Routing\RouteSubscriberBase for it. To me RouteSubscriberBase seems as redundant class since it does not add much.

Comment: yeah, so basically they messed up the rest thing !!

Comment: more details would help